# Upload and process csv in Django

Tags: python, django, csv

I want to upload a csv file in django.

1. API enabled to receive a csv, clean and structure the data, and return it in the call.
2. Have another API that says something interesting about the data it has received.

Here the top 3 lines of the csv:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SsZCK.png)

2022-06-07 07:10:58.314000,"{""data"": {""Sensor settings"": null}, ""offset"": {""Sensor settings_offset"": null}}"
2022-06-07 07:15:58.495000,"{""data"": {""Co2"": 152, ""Light"": 200, ""Humidity"": 0.47, ""Temperature"": 27.4, ""Motion (PIR)"": 0}, ""offset"": {""Co2_offset"": 0, ""Light_offset"": 0, ""Humidity_offset"": 0, ""Temperature_offset"": 0, ""Motion (PIR)_offset"": 0}}"
2022-06-07 07:25:58.303000,"{""data"": {""Co2"": 166, ""Light"": 195, ""Humidity"": 0.48, ""Temperature"": 27.3, ""Motion (PIR)"": 8}, ""offset"": {""Co2_offset"": 0, ""Light_offset"": 0, ""Humidity_offset"": 0, ""Temperature_offset"": 0, ""Motion (PIR)_offset"": 0}}"

Comment: Please show your attempt at this and share any issues with your attempt

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.